# Do Not Disturb keeps enabling itself on my Mac

Tags: mac, macos, do-not-disturb

Do Not Disturb on my Mac keeps enabling itself at midnight or after every reboot even though I do not have it scheduled. As you can see from the screenshot below, DND is not enabled at all. What could be causing DND to automatically enable? I am running El Capitan

[image]

Comment: I've seen this happen when you have DND on another i-device and both are signed-in with the same Apple ID. Is that the case here?

Comment: Sounds like a corrupted .plist file or cache to me. I'm too busy to hunt down the file where those would be stored right now, but maybe someone else can elaborate on this.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by editing `com.apple.notificationcenterui.<guid>.plist` and setting `dndEnd` and `dndStart` to zero.